# Opening a r file - getting script code instead

Tags: r

I'm trying to open a r file in r studio, but it opens some kind of a html file...

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xml:lang="en" class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><script type="text/javascript">
                window._document_observe_listeners = [];
                document.observe = function(event, func) {
                    window._document_observe_listeners.push({event: event, func: func});
                };

                window._jquery_ready_handlers = [];
                jQuery = function(handler) {
                    window._jquery_ready_handlers.push(handler);
                };

                function on_script_loaded(func) {
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Why do you think this is an R script and not something else (which it appears to be)?

Comment: because I had the same problem a few days ago and then it magically disappeared

Comment: Are you pulling the code files from the web somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, it saved for some reason the file in r format but it was something else

Comment: So this is resolved then?